# Object has no method sort

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with PHP to JavaScript and then sorting. I have the following JS script

```
function sortby(param, data) {
    switch (param) {
    case "aplha":
        console.log(data);
        data.sort();
        break;
    }
}
```

The array this is passing is through `json_encode` and the array looks like so

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => 123456 [Clean_Name] => 123456 [CreateDate] => 1372479841 ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => 123456 [Clean_Name] => 123456 [CreateDate] => 1372479841 ) )
```

However I get the above error when I try to pass it as `data.sort()`. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like your data is an object and not an array

Comment: what does     console.log(data) log ?

Comment: What is the `typeof data`? If it's a `String`, it'll need to be [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: I'm missing the part where your array is passed to JavaScript.

Comment: "I get the above error" -- you didn't post it. What error did you get?

Comment: Edited 
here is the call to the function 
<script>sortby('aplha', '<? print json_encode($newArray); ?>');</script>


here is the php script i have now


foreach ($array1 as $array2)
        $newArray[] = array_values($array2);

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays aren't js arrays, but JSON objects, so you can't have and array on your js code. However, there's a workaround, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/how-to-json-encode-php-array-to-a-json-array-not-as-a-json-object) answer for more info.

Cheers

Comment: i did this however its still not out putting correctly and still gives me that object has no method 'sort' error. Isn't there a way to convert the object to an array in javascript. I believe data.sort() only works if its an array. This method still passes it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found my issue however i dont know how to fix it. when i pass the variable with json_encode to the javascript function it passing it as a string so data[0] == [ ... what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

ALRIGHT wow i found my issue i am so sorry guys i am so dumb

```
<script>sortby('aplha', '<?=json_encode($teamList);?>');</script>
```

That was my old this is my new

```
<script>sortby('aplha', <?=json_encode($teamList);?>);</script>
```

It was the ' that was passing it incorrectly ... it works fine now I hit my desk so hard ...

Comment: If you have additions or clarifications, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18326242/edit) the question instead of posting a series of answers.