# PHP json_encode return rows as objects instead of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object, json

I am using json_encode() to encode array into json format. but it returning object instead of array. I want to return an array not an object.
any body have any idea?

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_values($array))` - is the simplest way to force an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically json_decode() will return two types of data.

```
1) Object 
2) Associative array
```

By default, json_decode() returns object type value.

But, if you want value as an array format you must use `TRUE` as a second argument in json_decode().

e.g,

```
$decoded_value = json_decode($json_encoded_value, TRUE);
```

Comment: json_encode and json_decode are different functions

Answer (score -1):

actually **json_encode** function in php will return a **json formatted string**.

and if you want to parse json formatted string back in php
then you should use **json_decode**.

json_decode function will return data two types.
object & associtavie array.

**json_decode(); return type object**

**json_decode(, TRUE); return type associtative array**

Answer (score -1):

use this code for decoding your encode json data

```
$encode = $your_json_encoded_data

json_decode($encode, TRUE);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `json_decode` with `TRUE` param like following example:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$encode = json_encode($array);

$decode = json_decode($encode, TRUE);
```

Now `$decode` is `array`, not object.

Comment: I am asking for json_encode not for json_decode. when we use JSON data from javascript.