# Angular search filter not working (data returned by PHP)

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I dont get the search filter working.

projects template:

```
<h3>Projekte</h3>
Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Long Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, project) in projects | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{project.title}}</td>
            <td>{{project.longTitle}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="edit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

controller:

```
var secProjects = function ($http,$scope, $modal) {

    $http.post('php/data.php').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
    })

}
```

php:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $data[$row->ID] = array ('id'=>$row->ID,'title'=>$row->Title,'longTitle'=>$row->TitleLong, 'textDE'=>$row->DescriptionDE,'start'=>$row->DateStart,'end'=>$row->DateEnd);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

i hope you can help me :( I think the reason ist the way i get the data in my scope. but iam not sure.

EDIT: Change the PHP solved the Problem:

```
   $data = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
      array_push($data,['id'=>$row->ID,'title'=>$row->Title,'longTitle'=>$row->TitleLong]);
   }
   echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: So, what do you expect and what do you actually see ?

Comment: i see a table filled with my data out of the mysql database, when i type something in the search input i expect to see a filtered table.

Comment: Sure $http.post is correct, i think $http.get is more appropriate. Additional try to initialise the searchText var in the controller with `$scope.searchText = '';`

Comment: yes iam sure because i see the data. $scope.searchText = '' dont change anything :(

Comment: @nofear87: This sure seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/XL2uA/ (with the post request). I guess there is an error in your code (not in your logic) - maybe a typograohic error. Try posting the entrire code or prepare a fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: instead of an array my php returns an object...i think thats the reason?

Comment: In that case you wouldn't see anything - nothing to do with the search filter.

Comment: You are already treating `projects` as an object, so...

Comment: I post the php Output in the Startpost..something like this: [{"id":"2","title":"NEWCOM","longTitle":"Network of Excellence in Wireless COMmunications","start":"2004","end":"2007"}] works...so i thing there is the mistake?

Comment: I'd recommend getting cozy with the Chrome development tools.

Comment: changing the php like in the start post solved the problem...can you explain to me why please?

Comment: @nofear87: See my answer below for an explanation. (Using `array_push($data, ...)`is essentially equivalent to `$data[] = ...`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your backend returns the data as an object instead of an array.
But the `filter` works only on arrays (according to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter)**):

> Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

---

So, you have two options:

**1.**
Before assigning the data to your scope, convert them from object to array. E.g.:

```
$http.post(...).success(function (data) {
    $scope.projects = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        $scope.projects.push(data[key]);
    }
});
```

**2.**
Have your backend return the data as a JSONified array, instead of an object.
The reason PHP is interpreting your `$data` "array" as an object is that the indices are not sequential (starting from 0). I.e. instead of having indices `0, 1, 2...`, you had `1,2,3...`. (See, **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/how-to-json-encode-php-array-to-a-json-array-not-as-a-json-object#11195796)** for more info.)
To fix this, you can change your code, like this:

```
$data[] = array (...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/XL2uA/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I've duplicated your work, without the service call [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gAnL8/).  It's exactly the same except for your post (should be a get).  And it works fine.  Take some more time to check your work.  Javascript errors may disable further functionality.
.

```
    $scope.projects = [{
    title: 'one',
    longTitle: 'one long title'
}, {
    title: 'two',
    longTitle: 'two long title'
}];
```

Comment: thank you! this instead of my http request works fine...but what you think it the reason? changing it to get change nothing.