# JQUERY/PHP: base64_encoded image data not displaying on CHROME, IE, OPERA

Tags: php, jquery, image, google-chrome, base64

I have images stored in BLOB format in my database. My PHP code can access this BLOB data and return it to client side HTML page in JSON format.

How do I display this data on my HTML page?

I have tried using base64_encode but it works only for Firefox.
THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING FOR CHROME, IE, OPERA.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$json2[] = array("Picture"=>base64_encode($row2[33]));
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
echo json_encode($json2);
```

And this is my JQuery code:

```
success: function(data){

        var str = JSON.stringify(data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);
        $('#pic0').html('<img  height="40" width="40" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + obj[0].Picture + '" />');
}
```

success function is a part of AJAX call.
My primary aim is to display this image in Mobile devices since this is a part of WebService Call.
From what i have read, it seems base64_encode has some limitations in working for every browser.

How can I display the images on HTML page?

I have checked other posts in SO but unable to find anything fruitful.

Comment: `$('where you want to display').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');` whats not working :?

Comment: what is your base64 image string ?

Comment: In your code line, I have changed the second 'data' with my picture data variable. Is that correct?

Comment: just show me complete code you have tried

Comment: $('#pic1').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + obj[0].Picture + '" />');
is my html code.
$json = array("Picture"=>base64_encode($row2[33]));
echo json;
is my php code

Comment: Show the view-source (Please update your QUESTION, do not just add a comment). Just creating an array does not make JSON - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/how-to-json-encode-php-array-to-a-json-array-not-as-a-json-object

Comment: I have updated the question. Is anything else required? I'm relatively new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code:

```
$json = array(/* anything */);
echo $json;
```

output the following to your page, verbatim:

```
Array
```

You need to echo like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
echo json_encode($json);
```

Of course your Javascript frontend must properly parse this JSON string to object you use in Javascript snippet you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:
As suggested by @NullPoiиteя, the encoded Blob data can be displayed using this code:

```
$('where you want to display').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + ImageVariable + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

> there's no base64_decode in javascript/jQuery?

That's not your problem. It's relatively trivial to write a base64_decode() implementation, however in order to display the data in the browser, you would still need canvas support - and if your browser does not support data URIs then it's unlikely to support canvas.

If it were me, I would use data URIs by default, but add detection in javascript to check for an absence of support, then update the src where data URI support is not available....

```
function check_img()
{
   var chkimg=document.getElementById("testDataUri");
   if (checkimg.height) {
       return true;
   }
   imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
   for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
     if (imgs[i].data && imgs[i].src.match(/data:/i) {
        imgs[i].src=imgs[i].data;
     }
   }
}
```

(code not tested - just for illustration purposes)