# Converting my php array to equivalent jQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, wordpress

I have an array in PHP and want to use that data inside my Jquery, I have converted that to json and here is my full code.

```
$mine = array(
'new' => 'new',
'old' => 'old'
);
```

and I have converted it like this

```
$result = json_encode(array_values($cat));
```

and now I got my results like show below:

```
[{"new":"new","old":"old"}]
```

this is wrong one, because I want it to be like this way.

```
[
{"new":"new"},
{"old":"old"}
]
```

I don't know where am I doing any thing wrong but I am unable to get this simple thing done ... any one to help me out of this simple question please ... I really have been through many earlier questions like [json_encode sparse PHP array as JSON array, not JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object)

But still unable to get this work for me, any one there to help me out pelase ???

Comment: Try to use `$result=json_encode($mine)` in php and `$.parseJSON(json)` in jQuery.

Comment: In the comments to an answer you showed your "actual code". Please put it in the question too, since it seems to be pretty different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array has to look like this in PHP:

```
$mine = array(
array('new' => 'new'),
array('old' => 'old')
);
```

json_encode transforms a php array to a json object ( {} )if it is a dictionary (Associative) and transforms it to a json array ( [] ) if it is a list without keys.

Comment: here is my actual code $cat = array();
 $categories = $categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => true));
 //print_r($categories);
 foreach($categories as $category){
  $cat['name'][$category->name] = $category->slug;
 }

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [another] => another
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Uncategorized] => uncategorized
        )

) now this is my array in php ... how can i make it like I already shown structure in jquery ?

Comment: This looks already right as your key/value pairs are inside extra array. Does json_encode not work correclty with this?

Answer (score 0):

You got a bit wrong structure of your php object it should be:

```
$mine = array(
   array('new' => 'new'),
   array('old' => 'old')
);
```

[Check example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43df99e2e268fbe204627f0d168ca7c1b97b5326).

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [another] => another ) [1] => Array ( [Uncategorized] => uncategorized ) ) now this is my array in php ... how can i make it like I already shown structure in jquery ?

Comment: the problem is that I am getting that data from ajax success method and then pushing that respone json to my jquery array ... then I want to use that array ... any one who can guide me properly plz ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
var encodedVar=json_encode($array_nm);
var js_array=$.paseJSON(encodedvar);
for(var i=0;i<js_array.length;i++){
    console.log(js_array[i]);//it will display value by index just like php array....
}
```