# PHP array to json without indices

Tags: php, arrays, json, data-conversion

I am new to PHP and I am trying to convert an array to json, without the indices.

For an example, I have:

```
[{"name":"Dean"},{"last_name":"Don"},{"age":31},{"height":181}]
```

I need it to be a single json object:

```
{
"name":"Dean,
"last_name":"Don",
"age":31,
"height":181
}
```

I tried using `json_encode()` but all I get is not correct, I event tried specifying
`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, which put the indices, which I don't want.

Anyone has an idea how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Show us what you tried, you may be closer to the answer than you think

Comment: Of course it would be **a better idea** to look at how you managed to create the first JSON String and fix that rather than try and fiddle with a bad result

Comment: Bot the array you wrote are not vaild php arrays.

Comment: @T30 I think that is a JSON String representation of an array of objects

Comment: A solution can be to do a [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and loop through the results to build your new array

Comment: ***Show us the code you used to create the initial JSON String***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to decode, merge and recode:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Dean"},{"last_name":"Don"},{"age":31},{"height":181}]';
$data = json_decode($json,true); // decode
$data = array_merge(...$data); // merge
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // recode
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "Dean", 
    "last_name": "Don", 
    "age": 31, 
    "height": 181 
}
```

Comment: I agree `array_merge` is perfect for this.

Comment: thank u , u saved my day

Answer (score 1):

did you try 
`json_encode(array_values($array))`?

Comment: Can you explain how this would help in creating a single JSON object?

Comment: see more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Not sure how that link has anything to do with this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode` to convert the json into an array. Use `array_reduce` to make a new array. Use `json_encode` to convert the array into a json again

```
$str = '[{"name":"Dean"},{"last_name":"Don"},{"age":31},{"height":181}]';

//Convert the json into array
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

//Make the multi dementional array into an associative array
$arr = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v){
    foreach ($v as $key => $val) $c[$key] = $val;
    return $c;
}, array());

//Convert the array to json
$result = json_encode($arr);

echo $result;
```

This will result to:

```
{"name":"Dean","last_name":"Don","age":31,"height":181}
```

Comment: It would still be better to fix the intial creation errors as the initial JSON String is really no use to man or beast

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of JSON looks like the result of encoding an array of key-value pairs like this:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'Dean'],
    ['last_name' => 'Don'],
    ['age' => 31],
    ['height' => 181]
];
```

If that's what you are starting with, you can iterate the set of attributes and construct an entity that will encode to a single object.

```
foreach ($data as $attribute) {
    $entity[key($attribute)] = reset($attribute);
}

echo json_encode($entity);
```

As mentioned in the comments, there *may be* a better way to do this earlier in your code, so you can create the entity you want in the first place instead of something like the `$data` example that you'll have to re-process before you can output it.