# i cant format json array to desired format

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have json array that i generate from php. However the format is not what i want. i have related questions but it is not the format i want Please see below what i did and tried vs what i want

```
    //////////////
$data variable array
///////////////

Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [start_date] => 2018-05-17 08:40
                [end_date] => 2018-05-17 09:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [start_date] => 2018-05-17 08:40
                [end_date] => 2018-05-17 09:00
            )
      )
```

This is what i do

```
$array[] = $data;
echo json_encode($array);
```

The output

```
[
 {"id":2,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"},
 {"id":3,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"}
]
```

This is what i tried

```
$array["data"] = $data;
echo json_encode($array);
```

The output

```
{"data":
 {"id":2,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"},
 {"id":3,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"}
}
```

The output i want

```
{
  "data": [
             {"id":2,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"},
             {"id":3,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"}
          ]
}
```

Comment: try $data[] and then put it inside your array

Comment: What is `$data`?

Comment: i am not following what you are saying. May you provide an example?

Comment: this is $data: $data['id']=2;$data['start_date']=2018-05-17; and so on @AlexShesterov

Comment: The 2nd output snippet is wrong then - it won't contain two objects without array (which is invalid json).

Comment: $data variable is a php array populated in a loop like so : $data['id']='2';
data['start_date']='2018-05-17 08:40'; 
$ata['end_date']='2018-05-17 08:40'; @AlexShesterov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to build an array first, then construct an object. See below

```
$array = [
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "start_date" => "2018-05-17 08:40",
        "end_date" => "2018-05-17 09:00"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "start_date" => "2018-05-17 08:40",
        "end_date" => "2018-05-17 09:00"
    ]
];
$data["data"] = $array;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i have an array, please edited code. i did exactly that but the output is as indicated on the third ouptut

Comment: This is strange. It looks like your first data variable array is not interpreted as a try array. Can you please var_dump it ? Point is : check this answer, looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `$array["data"]` i put "data" into an array an then another array for `$data`.

```
$array = array("data" => $data);
$enData = json_encode($array); //encoding array to json
$deData = json_decode($enData, true); //decoding array

print_r($deData);
```

The above would output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [start_date] => 2018-05-17 08:40
            [end_date] => 2018-05-17 09:00
        )

)
```

and if you do this:

```
print_r($deData['data']);

//Output

Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [start_date] => 2018-05-17 08:40
    [end_date] => 2018-05-17 09:00
)
```

Comment: Can you share some more context?

Comment: @JamesBond: Please edit your answer, include some information about what your code does and how it solves the problem/answers the question. Otherwise, it may be deleted as *Very Low Quality* or attract downvotes

Comment: @OurManinBananas Updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `$data` an array first.

For example:

```
$data[] = ["id" => 2, "start_date" => "2018-05-17 08:40", "end_date" => "2018-05-17 09:00"];

$array["data"] = $data;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data":[
           {"id":2,"start_date":"2018-05-17 08:40","end_date":"2018-05-17 09:00"}
         ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting the $data from loop over sql output:

```
$array = ["data"=>[]];// initialize $array outside your loop

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array['data'][] = $data;  // push $data into $array['data']
}

echo json_encode($array);
```