# How to get value from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

This is the array result that I get from a function. I want to get the category_id from the array and only echo it.

```
{"categories": [{"parent_id": 15397, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15402, "category_name": "AC"}, {"parent_id": 0, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15397, "category_name": "A"}], "request_id": "3beac0674e937d2471e4b66b5f998976"}
```

after I json_decode my result, it shows like this.

```
stdClass Object ( [categories] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [parent_id] => 0 [has_children] => 1 [category_id] => 16 [category_name] => Women's Clothing ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [parent_id] => 16 [has_children] => 1 [category_id] => 1585 [category_name] => Dresses )
```

How to access the category_id when there is 2 stdclass object

```
//solved it
foreach ($arr as $obj => $arr) {
            foreach ($arr as $obj => $arr) {
                print_r($arr->category_id);

            }

        }
```

Comment: `json_decode()` would be a good  start

Comment: @tim edited it after json_decode

Comment: set second param in `json_decode()` to `true` so you will have it as an associative array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode sparse PHP array as JSON array, not JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-sparse-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to have nested loop here because the first level is not array, but object.

```
$data = "{"categories": [{"parent_id": 15397, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15402, "category_name": "AC"}, {"parent_id": 0, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15397, "category_name": "A"}], "request_id": "3beac0674e937d2471e4b66b5f998976"}";

// Change to Array
$obj = json_decode($data, true);

// Get the data
foreach($obj['categories'] as $category) {
    print_r($category['category_id']);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, If i wanted to pass the category_id to another function, is it possible?

Comment: Just call ```fnName($category['category_id'])``` to call a function like normal php do

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 // Use this function to get the desired result, and then you can pass the result to another function
$data = '{"categories": [{"parent_id": 15397, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15402, "category_name": "AC"}, {"parent_id": 0, "has_children": true, "category_id": 15397, "category_name": "A"}], "request_id": "3beac0674e937d2471e4b66b5f998976"}';

function getCategoreIds($data=[]){
    $cids=[];
    $datas = json_decode($data,true);
    if($datas['categories']){
        foreach($datas['categories'] as $k=>$tmp){
            if(isset($tmp['category_id'])){
                $cids[] = $tmp['category_id'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $cids;
}

print_r(getCategoreIds($data));
```