# json_encode multidimensional array encodes to object instead of array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to encode 2 arrays in a multidimensional array with the same structure (see below), but they are encoded differently.

The only difference is that the second array has more elements in the `options` array (27 elements) than the first one (3 elements).

**The first one** encodes the `options` array as an array:

```
{"structure":[{"options":[{"label":"Label 1","value":"value-1"},{"label":"Label 2","value":"value-2"},{ ... etc
```

**The second one** encodes it as an object:

```
{"structure":[{"options":{"0":{"label":"Label 3","value":"value-3"},"1":{"label": "Label 4" ... etc
```

Now I try to use this JSON object as input for a Javascript script. The first one works and is interpreted as an array of objects, but the second one is interpreted as an object (so not iterable).

Does [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) have a flag to always force array structure (just as it has for force object) or do I have to create a custom function?

**Array structure:**

```
array(2) {
  ["structure"]=>
  array(9) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) { // Array 1 <-------
      ["options"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(7) "Label 1"
          ["value"]=>
          string(7) "value-1"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(9) "Label 2"
          ["value"]=>
          string(9) "value-2"
        }
        ...
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) { // Array 2 <------
      ["options"]=>
      array(27) { 
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(13) "Label 3"
          ["value"]=>
          string(13) "value-3"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(11) "Label 4"
          ["value"]=>
          string(11) "value-4"
        }
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you check your Array Index Order and if you have a sequence of Array Keys? See the answer to [json_encode PHP array as JSON array not JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object)

Comment: That is a good one I am going to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of the comment of @Uwe and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195692/json-encode-php-array-as-json-array-not-json-object), I found out that the problem occurred because there was (for some reason) an array index element skipped. When this happens [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) creates this object structure instead of an array.

To fix this I reindexed the `options` array with [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and that fixed my problem.