# Laravel - Responding JSON from Collection after sorted has item index as object key

Tags: php, json, laravel

I don't know what causes the problem, but below is the original PHP code which resulted with the wanted JSON format:

<sub>PHP</sub>

```
return response()->json($model->things, 200);
```

<sub>JSON</sub>

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
]
```

However, when I sorted the collection, the array in JSON became an object.

<sub>PHP</sub>

```
return response()->json($model->things->sortBy("name"), 200);
```

<sub>JSON</sub>

```
{
    "0": {...},
    "1": {...},
    ...
}
```

Did I do something wrong? I tried `dd`ing the collection in the 2 cases, but the results look the same to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From laravel documentation:

> The sortBy method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys

so after sortBy() you have something like this:

```
[2=>'val1', 1 => 'val2', 0 => 'val3']
```

and it's associative array, and that explains why in json it became an object, and to prevent this you need to use values() method like this:

```
$model->things->sortBy("name")->values()->all()
```

second question is why it is not sorted, and you can read this question: [json_encode not preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912492/json-encode-not-preserving-order)