# HMAC validation in GoLang

Tags: go, sha256, hmac

I have a HMAC validation code in PHP which is like

```php
$calculatedHmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', json_encode($input), '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', true));
if($calculatedHmac === $this->app['request']->header('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256')) 
{
    echo "Correct HMAC";
}
```

Now, I am trying to do the same validation in GoLang. The corresponding code:

```
hash := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte('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'))
inputData, _ := json.Marshal(input)
fmt.Println(string(inputData))
hash.Write(inputData)
base64EncodedStr := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
hexEncodedStr := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
if requestHmac == base64EncodedStr {
    logger.GetEntryWithContext(ctx).Infow("JsonMarshal.Base64 worked", nil)
} else if hexEncodedStr == requestHmac {
    logger.GetEntryWithContext(ctx).Infow("JsonMarshal.Hex Encoding worked", nil)
}
```

Anything that I am doing wrong???

Input data:
Actual HMAC: `EUF2feuOuaQzh0bhSE8eCaI23BM0Qh+yBtmxNWyt8JQ=`

JSON Input:

```
{"address1":"Ghar ka Address","address2":null,"auto_configure_tax_inclusivity":null,"checkout_api_supported":false,"city":"Bangalore ","cookie_consent_level":"implicit","country":"IN","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India","county_taxes":true,"created_at":"2021-03-06T11:54:22+05:30","currency":"INR","customer_email":"amit.vickey@razorpay.com","domain":"rzp-sample-store.myshopify.com","eligible_for_card_reader_giveaway":false,"eligible_for_payments":false,"email":"amit.vickey@razorpay.com","enabled_presentment_currencies":["INR"],"finances":true,"force_ssl":true,"google_apps_domain":null,"google_apps_login_enabled":null,"has_discounts":false,"has_gift_cards":false,"has_storefront":true,"iana_timezone":"Asia/Calcutta","id":55091921055,"latitude":12.9142148,"longitude":77.61210129999999,"money_format":"Rs. {{amount}}","money_in_emails_format":"Rs. {{amount}}","money_with_currency_format":"Rs. {{amount}}","money_with_currency_in_emails_format":"Rs. {{amount}}","multi_location_enabled":true,"myshopify_domain":"rzp-sample-store.myshopify.com","name":"RZP Sample Store","password_enabled":true,"phone":"","plan_display_name":"Developer Preview","plan_name":"partner_test","pre_launch_enabled":false,"primary_locale":"en","primary_location_id":61106618527,"province":"Karnataka","province_code":"KA","requires_extra_payments_agreement":false,"setup_required":false,"shop_owner":"Amit Vickey","source":null,"tax_shipping":null,"taxes_included":false,"timezone":"(GMT+05:30) Asia/Calcutta","updated_at":"2021-03-06T12:06:18+05:30","visitor_tracking_consent_preference":"allow_all","weight_unit":"kg","zip":"560076"}
```

Comment: Are the JSON encodings in PHP and Go the same?

Comment: json_encode converts to JSON string, and json.Marshal converts into byte array which upon doing string(bytes) returns the same JSON. So yes the JSON encodings are same I guess.

Comment: Look at the actual strings to confirm that they are identical. The encoders might use different string encodings, whitespace between tokens and field orders.

Comment: order of the fields will also matter @CeriseLimón ?

Comment: If the two encoders write the fields in different orders, then the input to the HMAC is different.  If the input to the HMAC is different, then the HMAC result will be different.

Comment: The code looks good. Use a simple one property JSON object like `{"foo":"bar"}` to confirm. The Base64 encoded value should match the PHP output. The issue as others have mentioned is JSON key order in JSON encoding. See this issue for more: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27179  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912492/json-encode-not-preserving-order

Comment: sure will try this. another doubt, just relevant this this only. In GoLang I have to write utility that if a map have index as keys like `{"0":"abc","1":"bcd","2":"def"}`, I need to  an array of values out of it  i.e. `["abc", "bcd", "def"]`

Comment: Comparing MACs like this creates a vulnerability which can be exploited using side-channel attacks! In Go, the correct way to compare HMACs is to use `hmac.Equal()`. In PHP, the function is named `hash_equals()`.