# Force Serializer Symfony to return an array instead of an object

Tags: arrays, symfony, object, serialization

There is my function :

```
private function responseJson($datas, $code)
{
    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
    $context = new SerializationContext();
    $context->setSerializeNull(true);
    $response = new Response($serializer->serialize($datas, 'json', $context->enableMaxDepthChecks()), $code);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

I use serializer components of symfony. This is what my server do when I call this function. The client need an array but the server returns an object. Is it possible to force to return an array ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: You can possibly convert your object into an array before sending it as a response. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: I already tried to cast `$datas = (array)$datas`. But it doesn't work

Comment: Such problem also may be relevant with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104868/symfony-4-doctrine-2-serialize-after-removing-first-item-from-collection-cau/56867626#56867626

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the [JsonSerializationVisitor](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php#L29) the actual encoding is done with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$result = @json_encode($this->getRoot(), $this->options);
```

As I can read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559703/i-would-like-json-encode-in-php-to-return-a-json-array-even-if-the-indices-are-n) the forced creation of an array with json_encode cannot be done.

If your input data would be an array without indices, then json_encode would produce an array. That means that if key names in your data do matter, you cannot return an array to the client.

Comment: Okay, I consider again results given, and there are keys. So as you said, Client can't get an array. So I try an `array_values($datas)` to remove keys, but It doesn't work.

Comment: I've made a quick project in Symfony 2.7.7, installed jms/serializer-bundle and pasted your code into the controller. I've given that controller three different arrays treated with array_values. You can [see the code here](http://pastebin.com/jqvVXdUr). No matter which array I choose, I always get an array as a response. I cannot imagine that your `$datas` array can cause the response to be an object, but maybe you can show an example of how it looks like?

Comment: Thanks for you for what you did. And what happened if $datas is already an object and not an array ? It will return an object, will it ?

Comment: Yes, it will. In order to get an array out of `json_encode` you must have an array with no indices as an input.